# How to sort a character vector according to a specific order?

Tags: r

I've got a character vector which looks like

```
c("white","white","blue","green","red","blue","red")
```

and a specific order which is like

```
c("red","white","blue","green")
```

. I would like to sort the first vector according to the order of the second vector in order to obtain the following vector : `c("red","red","white","white","blue","blue", "green")`. 
What would be the best solution ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
x <- c("white","white","blue","green","red","blue","red")
y <- c("red","white","blue","green")
x[order(match(x, y))]
# [1] "red"   "red"   "white" "white" "blue"  "blue"  "green"
```

Answer (score 13):

Make your variable into a factor with the levels in the appropriate order and `sort()`:

```
 x1 <- c("white","white","blue","green","red","blue","red")
 ord <- c("red","white","blue","green")
 f1 <- factor(x1,levels=ord)
 sort(f1)
 ## [1] red   red   white white blue  blue  green
 ## Levels: red white blue green
```

You can use `x2 <- as.character(sort(f1))` if you really want the results as a character vector ...