# What is the most efficient method to sort the values of a column into a specific order?

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I am using R and ggplot2 to construct a data visualization which will use the values in a specific column (called `MthYr`) of my data set as its x-axis values.
The `MthYr` column is derived from another column which is a date column called `Date`. An extract is shown below:

```
 Date           MthYr
 2014-06-05     Jun 2014
 2014-07-30     Jul 2014
 ...            ...
 2017-08-03     Aug 2017
```

The data set comes from a CSV file and the `MthYr` column is a text column.

I need to create a plot in ggplot2 that will use the values of `MthYr` on its x-axis. I want the values to be correctly sorted from Jun 2014 to Aug 2017.

Answers to this stackoverflow question does seem to provide a solution but it is tedious to specifically write down the order from Jun 2014 to Aug 2017:
[How to sort a character vector according to a specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031039/how-to-sort-a-character-vector-according-to-a-specific-order)

Is there another more efficient way that I can do this?

Comment: You will want to make sure your date column is a date object, for `scale_x_date` to work. you can coerce objects into dates with `as.Date` and a format argument. Your ggplot will look something like: `ggplot(data, aes(x = MthYr, y = some_variable) + geom_point() + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%M")`

Comment: Since you have month and year only, you should check out package `zoo`,  function `as.yearmon`. The other solution is to paste your partial date with some day, such as `1`. Something like `as.Date(paste("1", "Jun 2014"), "%d %b %Y")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

say your plot is p. use:

```
p + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%M")
```

You might also want to read [this documentation](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html). :)

Comment: If I understand well, I simply need to use the Date column of my data set and format it accordingly.

Comment: That's correct. The date column **is your x axis**, and you simply add the "layer" `scale_x_date(...)` onto the ggplot object to tell ggplot, "alright, so my x axis is a vector of dates, and now i'm adding this scale and specifying where the dates break, and how they are labeled."