# How to order a character vector according to a second character vector made up of substrings of the first?

Tags: r

I want to sort a character vector that looks like this:

```
x <- c("white","white","blue","green","red","blue","red")
```

according to a specific order that looks like this:

```
y <- c("r","white","bl","gree")
```

If the second vector would be spelled out, the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031039/how-to-sort-a-character-vector-according-to-a-specific-order). However, in reality my first character vector has very long entries and the second vector has much shorter but still long entries. All entries are of different character length. My goal still is `c("red","red","white","white","blue","blue", "green")`. I actually only have unique entries in both vectors but I guess the question will be more useful if we have a general answer? How could I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep` in combination with `sapply`. But it will only work when there is no overlap in `y`. It will only return hits between `x` and `y`. With `^` you say that it need to be at the begin. `value = TRUE` says that it should return the string where it has a hit.

```
unlist(sapply(paste0("^",y), grep, x, value = TRUE))
#    ^r1     ^r2 ^white1 ^white2    ^bl1    ^bl2   ^gree 
#  "red"   "red" "white" "white"  "blue"  "blue" "green"
```

The following will also work with an overlap in y and takes the first hit.

```
x  <- c(x, "redd"); y  <- c(y, "redd")

x[unique(unlist(sapply(paste0("^",y), grep, x)))]
#[1] "red"   "red"   "redd"  "white" "white" "blue"  "blue"  "green"
```

or get the last hit:

```
x[unique(unlist(sapply(paste0("^",y), grep, x)), fromLast = TRUE)]
[1] "red"   "red"   "white" "white" "blue"  "blue"  "green" "redd"
```

To get all x and place the no-match and the end you can use:

```
x  <- c(x, "yellow")

x[unique(c(unlist(sapply(paste0("^",y), grep, x)), seq_along(x)))]
[1] "red"    "red"    "redd"   "white"  "white"  "blue"   "blue"   "green" 
[9] "yellow"
```

Comment: fantastic! Of course, your can't have overlaps in y. But this code still works even if we add a "redd" to both vectors which is great! Could you elaborate on the grep command? The ^ is a regular expression saying what exactly? And value = TRUE just means it looks for exact matches? I never really get the difference between this one and the perl = TRUE argument. ps.: you have a comma to many

Comment: If you add "redd" to both sides you will get it also when asking for "r".

Comment: Or you can do this without a loop `x[order(factor(setNames(y, c("red", "white", "blue", "green"))[x], levels = y))]`