# Reorder plot legend categories in a terra SpatVector map

Tags: r, legend, terra

Is there a way to have the plot legend categories in a specific order with a SpatVector map of package terra? Example:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
head(v)
plot(v, "NAME_1")
```

[image]

How can we get "Luxembourg" to appear first in the legend, and also the remaining categories in a user-specified order? We've tried converting the "NAME_1" column to factor, but it's still interpreted as character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the argument `sort=FALSE`. In that case, the legend will be in the same order as what is returned by `unique("fieldname")`

Example data

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
```

If we wanted to map "NAME_1" alphabetically, except with "Luxembourg" on top, you could do

```
# make sure names are sorted 
v <- v[order(v$NAME_1), ]
# put Luxembourg on top
vv <- rbind(v[v$NAME_1 == "Luxembourg", ], v[v$NAME_1 != "Luxembourg", ])

plot(vv, "NAME_1", sort=FALSE)
```

[image]

---

`terra` version 1.5.38 (currently the development version) now has these two additional options:

Sort in decreasing order

```
plot(v, "NAME_2", decreasing=TRUE)
```

[image]

Sort in a specified order (or random, as in this example)

```
set.seed(66)
u <- unique(v$NAME_2) |> sample()
plot(v, "NAME_2", sort=u)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I guess we can combine it with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031039/how-to-sort-a-character-vector-according-to-a-specific-order) if we want all other categories also in a specific order.

Comment: Yes, specifically, they will be in the order returned by `unique` (see expanded answer)

Comment: One additional problem that arises is that NAs are now plotted with an additional colour: `v[1, "NAME_1"] <- NA;
plot(v, "NAME_1");
unique(v$NAME_1);
ord <- c("Luxembourg", "Grevenmacher", "Diekirch");
vv <- v[order(match(v$NAME_1, ord)), ];
plot(vv, "NAME_1", sort = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit tricky solution. You can manually set a legend in your plot using the base R `legend` function. You can use the following code:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
head(v)
plot(v, "NAME_1")
legend("topright", legend = c("Luxembourg", "Grevenmacher", "Diekrich"), fill = c("green", "blue", "deeppink"), bty = "n")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks -- this could also work (in the absence of a more practical solution), but it requires knowing how to specify each of the colours that appear on the map, which can get complicated especially for variables with more categories (e.g., `plot(v, "NAME_2")`).